# Get From properties using reflection

Tags: c#, winforms, reflection

I'm accessing form properties on this way:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly myAssembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly();
Type[] Types = myAssembly.GetTypes();
foreach (Type myType in Types)
{
    if (myType.BaseType == null) continue;
    
    if (myType.BaseType == typeof(Form))
    {                    
        var emptyCtor = myType.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes);
        if (emptyCtor != null)                    
        {
            var f = (Form)emptyCtor.Invoke(new object[] { });
            string FormText = f.Text;
            string FormName = f.Name;
            string btype = myType.BaseType.FullName;        

        }
    }
}
```

But each time when Form is accessed the Constructor is called and everything inside constructor is executed. How to avoid this?

Comment: @madreflection  Properties like form Text and form Name. I need those values but i don't need an instance of Form.

Comment: You *do* need an instance to get them. They're *instance* properties.

Comment: What is the expected behavior?  Do you only want the code section with the call to  myType.GetConstructor to be executed once?

Comment: @madreflection no any other way to do that? I have some Forms which execute something inside Constructor which should not be executed if Forms is not loaded.

Comment: @DanCsharpster I just want to go through all forms in my project and for each form get property like form name and form text without executing Constructor of each form.

Comment: Perhaps you should "promote" those values to attributes (which do not require an instance to retrieve) and then 1) query the attributes in the above method, and 2) populate the form instances' properties from the attributes.

Comment: @madreflection This is good idea with attributes. I'm experimenting with this right now, could work.... But I'm wondering is there any way to access to form properties value during runtime if form is not instantiated...

Comment: Absolutely not. Those properties are *instance* properties so you must have an *instance* to retrieve their values.  Extracting them to instance-independent metadata alleviates that restriction (while introducing some complexity, of course).

Comment: You can get all Forms names with, e.g., `var formNames = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().GetTypes().Where(t => t.BaseType== typeof(Form)).Select(f => f.FullName).ToList();`, but the `Text` property is assigned when the Form instance is first initialized, so there's no Text at this point.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the names of the properties for that specific type, then you should just iterate through the types.  There is a good example of that [here](https://www.codeproject.com/questions/826208/how-to-get-form-title-form-text-by-form-name-winfo)

Comment: Per the comment above: *"Properties like form Text and form Name. I need those **values**"*. That's not going to solve the problem because it only gets the type name.